# What is the [video] tag supposed to be?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) seems to be an ambiguous mashup of things related to movie-media files and issues with output hardware. There is a [media](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media) which is sometimes (but not always) combined with [video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) but it doesn't seem to add a lot of clarity being a rather mixed bag itself.

We already have tags for lots of common video formats (e.g. [quicktime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quicktime), [mov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mov)) as well as video related actions ([video-encoding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-encoding), [video-editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-editing)). Most movie related programs have their own ([mplayer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mplayer), [vlc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vlc)).

On the video hardware side of things [nvidia](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) already has a place and a generic [hardware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) sometimes gets tacked on to clarify that which half of [video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) is meant.

- Would it make sense to split [video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) into two tags?
- If so, can anybody suggest a good set of tags?

Comment: [tag:graphics] is similarly abused, it's mainly but not only about graphics hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple naming suggestion: [video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) can be split into:

- [video-formats](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-formats) sub-category of [media](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media) with famous formats as sub-tags
- [video-hardware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-hardware) sub-category of [hardware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware), with famous brands as sub-tags.

This would complete the [video-encoding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-encoding), [video-editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-editing),… list, thus allowing a general selection of "video-*" tags.

Answer (score 2):

I believe common words such as video, graphic, software are not suitable to be a tag as in the word `thing`. This kind of tags are always tend to be abused and make search result quality worse.

As you mentioned, there are already many specific tags for formats, softwares, hardwares and techics; so in my opinion there is no need to use video tag and it may be splitted into two or more tags.